# I am trying to get data from database and display them on cards. But got an error 'Unexpected response format from server'

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, material-ui, mern

I am beginner to MERN stack and I am trying to get card details from database and display them in cards. But I got above error displaying on card.I can get card details through Postman, but can't display in front end.
Here is my code. Please help me to make it correct.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { Button, CardActionArea, CardActions } from '@mui/material';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function ProductItems() {

  const [product, setProduct] = useState([{
    title: '',
    prize: '',
    img: ''
   }]);
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => { 
  
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/getProduct')
  .then(res => {
    if(res.data.status === 'success' && res.data.product){
      setProduct(res.data.data.product);
    }else{
      setError('Unexpected response format from server');
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if(err.response && err.response.status === 403){
      setError('Access Denied');
    }else{
      setError('Error fetching from server');
    }
  });
},[]);


  var cardStyle = {
    display: 'block',
    width: '30vw',
    height: '45vw',
    
}


  return (
    <div>
       
   

    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }} style={cardStyle}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
         {product.map((product,index) => (
            <li key={index}>{product.img}</li>
          ))}
          
        />
        <CardContent paddingTop={'500'}>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h4" component="div"  paddingTop={'500px'}>
         <ul>
          {product.map((product,index) => (
            <li key={index}>{product.title}</li>
          ))}
         </ul>
       </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5" color="text.secondary">
          <ul>
          {product.map((product,index) => (
            <li key={index}>{product.prize}</li>
          ))}
         </ul> 
        

          </Typography>
          {error && <p style={{color:'red'}}>{error}</p>}
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="medium" variant="contained" sx={{bgcolor:"#c85959", "&:hover":{bgcolor:"#4f0b0b"}}}>
          Shop Now
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>



    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the product model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
    title: {type: String, required:true, unique:true},
    prize:{type:Number, required:true, unique:true},
    description: {type:String, required:true},
    img: {type:String, required:true},
    categories: {type:Array, required:true},
    size: {type:Array, required:true},
    colour: {type:String, required:true},
    
},
{timestamps: true}
    );

 module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

This is the getProduct route

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Product = require("../database/models/Product")

router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
    const product = await Product.find({});
    try{
        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            data:{
                product
            }
        });
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({
            status: 'Failed', 
        });
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Please help me to correct this

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, the first thing I'd do is log the response received from the request. This will help you debug the issue.

One more thing, in the case of using then, there is no need to recheck the status for a `success`.

Also, in your condition, you are checking for `res.data.product` while you are setting `res.data.data.product`. Ensure consistency in the property names. Reviewing these details should guide you in solving the issue on your own. Hopefully, this helps.